# prevent git from overriding tracked ignored files during a pull

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore, git-pull

So there is a file that is already tracked by git call it file.php...This is in a collaborative environment

I made changes to that file that I don't want to have it committed but I want the changes to stay in my local environment so I did this

```
1. git update-index --assume-unchanged file.php
2. Added file.php to gitignore
```

And the changes to the file won't get committed, etc, which is working fine

The problem is...whenever I do a `git pull origin master`, the pull always attempts to override that file

I tried doing `git rm --cached file.php` but that will untrack the file and requires a commit and I don't want to affect the central repository when ignoring this..

How do I get git to ignore a tracked file during a pull?

Comment: I don't wanna stash everytime I do a pull, which happens really often

Comment: rebase is a tabu as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`gup` script](http://jasoncodes.com/posts/gup-git-rebase) is made for you: it stashes your changes, pull, and pops your changes, so you will be able to update your repository without git shouting at you.

There's also the [`git-up` script](https://github.com/aanand/git-up) that is more clever, but Windows support looks incomplete at this time.